# sweetAlert not working for IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, sweetalert

I'm trying to open the same url on IE but there is one problem.
The sweetAlert is not working. [Here](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert) I was trying to find any Info about IE compatibility 
for sweetAlert. But there is nothing related to IE compatibility.
Is there any alternative available of sweetAlert with IE compatibility.

Comment: you should probably open an issue on github and also provide more info like which version of IE you are using.

Comment: which version of IE are you targeting?

Comment: Its not working for IE8

Comment: To Include a polyfill for ES6 Promises (optional) for IE11, UC Browser and Android browser support try including https://unpkg.com/promise-polyfill

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Read this issue

- https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert/issues/69 or https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert/search?q=IE&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Have you tried [this](http://ned.im/noty/) plugin ?

Comment: not even close to an answer for what the person is asking...